# How does a Kafka Consumer behave if a Producer goes down. What happens to the data in the interval when the producer goes down

Tags: apache-kafka

I just want to know how the Consumer is able to consume data when the producer is down. Let's say Producer keeps sending logs to the consumer at a steady rate and then the producer goes down from 8AM- 6PM. How does the consumer work in such a case and is there a way that the consumer can get the data that would have been sent during 8am - 6pm if the producer was up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kafka doc has a nice diagram which I copied below. It shows the novelty of Kafka in a succinct way.
[image]

Without Kafka, the situation is something like this. We have multiple servers, e.g. Frontend servers, DB servers, Chat servers etc. On the other side, we have probably different metrics and monitoring tools (e.g. DB monitor, UI monitor etc.). Direct one-to-one communications between different servers and collectors might work out for smaller systems, but it breaks down pretty quickly after the system has surpassed a a certain threshold, in terms of scalability. Kafka solves this problem by decoupling the senders and receivers. Both of them talk through the Kafka brokers instead of talking to each other.

So, in your case the consumer would simply ask the broker if there's any new data on the topic it's subscribing to. As the producer is down, and assuming there is no data in the queue, broker would reply, *there's nothing to be consumed.*. So, the consumer would be perpetually polling in a fixed interval, in an endless loop and do nothing. Whenever the producer comes up and starts pumping out data, consumer would start receiving (and processing) it. There are more involved use cases when you might be losing data if retention period for particular topic is over, and the consumer hasn't processed the backlog. But I don't think that's a concern for you at this point of your journey.

Answer (score 1):

In Apache Kafka there is no relationship between how producer and consumer behaves.
Acting as a messaging system, Kafka allows to decoupling producer from a consumer providing an asynchronous communication channel.
The producer can send messages at its own pace and the consumer can read these messages in real time or later at its own pace (different from the producer one).
The messages are saved in a topic living in the Kafka cluster, and each message has a position in the topic partition (offset).
Of course, it's possible to tune when messages are deleted from the topic if the consumer isn't online for long time reading the messages.
You can set to store messages for very long time (days, weeks, months) and after that they will be deleted; or you can set to store messages based on time (so deleting the ones older than a time).
Furthermore, the consumer is also able to rewind the stream of messages in the topic, actually re-reading the messages if needed.
Finally, the consumer can also seek to a specific position in the topic partition based on offset or specifiying a time.